# How can I insert values of one list into another by using the values of the other lists an index into the first? (Python)

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists:

```
list1 = [[2, 4], [3], [0, 4], [1], [0, 2], []]
list2 = [12000,24000,14000,22000,13000,30000]
```

How can I insert the values of list2 into list1 by the corresponding index position, so that the output would be:

```
list3 = [[14000, 13000], [22000], [12000, 13000], [24000], [12000, 14000], []]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`list3 = [[list2[y] for y in x] for x in list1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 = [[2, 4], [3], [0, 4], [1], [0, 2], []]
list2 = [12000,24000,14000,22000,13000,30000]
for i in list1:
    for k,j in enumerate(i):
        i[k]=list2[j]
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[[14000, 13000], [22000], [12000, 13000], [24000], [12000, 14000], []]
```

Here is a compact solution:

```
List3=[[list2[x] for x in i] for i in list1]
print(list3)
```